# How to fix references when sharing a Netbeans project with subversion?

Tags: svn, jsf, netbeans, reference

Me and my friend are trying to manage a project with subversion, but every time one of us updates/downloads latest version, problems with references occur.
This has to do with the references "`mysql..connector..jar`" and "`myfaces..bundle..jar`". The important thing is that we have the same version of the libraries, we made sure of that, but still when one of us has updated to latest version and starts Netbeans, we get

> "..One or more references could not be found.."

So I'm wondering if we could put these two libraries/jars in the project folder and solve it that way. I think that right now it's like an external reference, I have the jars on my desktop and have to link to them every time I have a new version of the project.

More details: JSF project with Netbeans, we're using TortoiseSVN (Subversion).

Hope someone understands, maybe with some questions I can make myself more clear.

EDIT: so now I tried resolving the problem by finding these jars in the project folder and adding them again, it worked. But why is netbeans complaining if the jars are already in the project? One would assume netbeans can find them automatically.

EDIT 2: I also noticed now that project.properties and private.properties (2 files in the project) are marked red, do we have to have the same version of Tomcat server? That seems to be the conflict in project.properties.

EDIT 3: Some files contain file paths, which are different on our computers (C:\Users\MyPC.. vs. C:\Users\HisPC..) Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following comments may be helpful:

1. Never import the \nbproject\private folder into svn. It is automatically created by Netbeans every time you open the project.
2. Try to gather all the third party libs in a separate repo. Then use svn:external to refer to them.
3. Use relative references in your project. Use ../../Lib/X.jar instead of c:\user\jones\X.jar

Comment: Ah this seems to be the way tos olve it, not exactly sure how to do it now though :) I'll read more about it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just right click on the project.. there will be an option for resolve conflicts.. if the option is not directly visible go to subversion and in its sub menu u will surely get "Resolve Conflicts".

Use "Build with dependencies" option periodically... instead of just plain "clean and build"...

Comment: Yeah we've been told to use clean and build before, so that's what we've been using. I'll give that a go, thanks. 
It doesn't solve the problem though, surely this isn't how people work? There has to be a way to avoid this problem in the future, right?

Comment: I couldn't find "Build with dependencies"